# Import Excel data from Excel through power query

Tags: excel, vba, powerquery

I'm trying to load data from a csv file into an excel file with a power query with a name = file's name of the day (no issue getting it, it is then stored into a string var named "LatestFileQuery")
The problem happens at the end of the code when the query is refreshed.
My hypothesis is that it doesn't find the query mentioned earlier in "Location".
Would you know how to define and then refer to the query name ?

```
ActiveWorkbook.Queries.Add Name:= _
        **LatestFileQuery**, Formula:= _
        "let" & Chr(13) & "" & Chr(10) & "    Source = Csv.Document(File.Contents(""" & LatestFile & """),[Delimiter="";"", Columns=34, Encoding=1252, QuoteStyle=QuoteStyle.None])," & Chr(13) & "" & Chr(10) & "    #""Promoted Headers"" = Table.PromoteHeaders(Source, [PromoteAllScalars=true])," & Chr(13) & "" & Chr(10) & "    #""Changed Type"" = Table.TransformColumnTypes(#" & _
        """Promoted Headers"",{{""PORTFOLIO"", type text}, {""INSTRUMENT"", type text}, {""DEPOSIT"", type text}, {""CONTRACT ID"", type text}, {""INSTRUMENT NATURE"", type text}, {""QUANTITY ATLAS"", type number}, {""QUANTITY AAA"", type number}, {""DELTA QUANTITY"", type number}, {""NAV ATLAS"", type number}, {""NAV AAA"", type number}, {""PERCENTAGE NAV"", type number}, {" & _
        """DELTA NAV"", type number}, {""PRICE ATLAS"", type number}, {""DATE ATLAS"", type date}, {""PRICE AAA"", type number}, {""DATE AAA"", type date}, {""DELTA PRICE"", type number}, {""ACCRUED ATLAS"", type number}, {""ACCRUED AAA"", type number}, {""PERCENTAGE ACCRUED"", type number}, {""DELTA ACCRUED"", type number}, {""CURRENCY ATLAS"", type text}, {""CURRENCY AAA""" & _
        ", type text}, {""DELTA CURRENCY"", type number}, {""PMA ATLAS"", type number}, {""PMA AAA"", type number}, {""PERCENTAGE PMA"", type number}, {""DELTA PMA"", type number}, {"" RM/PM"", type text}, {"" MGT TYPE"", type text}, {"" NAV PTF (ATL)"", type number}, {"" NAV PTF (PMS)"", type number}, {"" NAV TOT"", type number}, {"" %NAVPTF"", type number}})" & Chr(13) & "" & Chr(10) & "in" & Chr(13) & "" & Chr(10) & "    #""Ch" & _
        "anged Type"""
    With ActiveSheet.ListObjects.Add(SourceType:=0, Source:=Array( _
        "OLEDB;Provider=Microsoft.Mashup.OleDb.1;Data Source=$Workbook$;Location=**""" & LatestFileQuery & """**;" _
        , "Extended Properties="""""), Destination:=Range("$A$1")).QueryTable
        .CommandType = xlCmdSql
        .CommandText = Array( _
        "SELECT * FROM [**LatestFileQuery**]")
        .RowNumbers = False
        .FillAdjacentFormulas = False
        .PreserveFormatting = True
        .RefreshOnFileOpen = False
        .BackgroundQuery = True
        .RefreshStyle = xlInsertDeleteCells
        .SavePassword = False
        .SaveData = True
        .AdjustColumnWidth = True
        .RefreshPeriod = 0
        .PreserveColumnInfo = True
        .ListObject.DisplayName = _
        **"" & LatestFileQuery & ""**
        .Refresh BackgroundQuery:=False
    End With
```

got the below error message:

[image: error]

Thanks for your help :)

Swan

Comment: Were you trying to make this part bold? `[**LatestFileQuery**]` - Or is that what the code looks like?

Comment: I would use the debugger to stop the code immediately after you have addded the query and check that the query is actually working.  It's the `"SELECT * FROM [**LatestFileQuery**]")` that is probably throwing that exception.
I personally, would have a named range work out what the name of the file should be and a fixed Query (built using the PQ Editor) - far easier to debug